# Java AppCDS collected on different VMs

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, classpath

The sign that AppCDS works are logs containing statements like this:

```
[22.785s][info][class,load] io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder source: shared objects file
[22.785s][info][class,load] io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecompressor source: shared objects file
```

on the other hand if AppCDS is not working, logs would be like this:

```
[22.516s][info][class,load] io.netty.channel.socket.ServerSocketChannel source: file:/app/libs/netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar
[22.516s][info][class,load] io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollServerChannel source: file:/app/libs/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.89.Final.jar
```

e.g. files will be loaded from the jar which is not quite what AppCSD is.

The first logs retrieved when I use CDS dump created on the same machine where I run JVM (I followed [this](https://dev.java/learn/jvm/cps-appcds/)) tutorial. Second logs sample is retrieved when I run application on the same VM but use CDS dump created on another VM with similar configuration(OS family, JVM family). The second VM in my case is Gitlab Runner. I made gradle task which implements the same steps as per tutorial to create CDS and put it into docker image.

Here is the info of VM where I run application:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Rocky Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Green Obsidian)"
ID="rocky"
ID_LIKE="rhel centos fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Rocky Linux 8.6 (Green Obsidian)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:rocky:rocky:8:GA"
HOME_URL="https://rockylinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.rockylinux.org/"
ROCKY_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Rocky Linux"
ROCKY_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Rocky Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8"
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.0Gi        12Gi       8.0Mi       1.9Gi        14Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7) (build 17.0.7+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7) (build 17.0.7+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

JVM CDS related logs when running application with dump made on that VM:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xlog:cds=debug -Xlog:class+load:file=/acds/cds.log
[0.006s][info][cds] trying to map /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.6.0.10-3.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/classes.jsa
[0.006s][info][cds] Opened archive /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.6.0.10-3.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/classes.jsa.
[0.007s][info][cds] Archive was created with UseCompressedOops = 1, UseCompressedClassPointers = 1
[0.007s][info][cds] Core region alignment: 4096
[0.007s][info][cds] Reserved archive_space_rs [0x0000000800000000 - 0x0000000800c00000] (12582912) bytes
[0.007s][info][cds] Reserved class_space_rs   [0x0000000800c00000 - 0x0000000840c00000] (1073741824) bytes
[0.007s][info][cds] Mapped static  region #0 at base 0x0000000800000000 top 0x0000000800458000 (ReadWrite)
[0.007s][info][cds] Mapped static  region #1 at base 0x0000000800458000 top 0x0000000800be1000 (ReadOnly)
[0.014s][info][cds] CDS archive was created with max heap size = 1964M, and the following configuration:
[0.014s][info][cds]     narrow_klass_base = 0x0000000800000000, narrow_klass_shift = 0
[0.014s][info][cds]     narrow_oop_mode = 0, narrow_oop_base = 0x0000000000000000, narrow_oop_shift = 0
[0.014s][info][cds]     heap range = [0x0000000085400000 - 0x0000000100000000]
[0.014s][info][cds] The current max heap size = 3956M, HeapRegion::GrainBytes = 2097152
[0.014s][info][cds]     narrow_klass_base = 0x0000000800000000, narrow_klass_shift = 0
[0.014s][info][cds]     narrow_oop_mode = 1, narrow_oop_base = 0x0000000000000000, narrow_oop_shift = 3
[0.014s][info][cds]     heap range = [0x0000000708c00000 - 0x0000000800000000]
[0.014s][info][cds] CDS heap data needs to be relocated because the archive was created with an incompatible oop encoding mode.
[0.014s][info][cds] CDS heap data relocation delta = 30064771072 bytes
[0.014s][info][cds] CDS heap data needs to be relocated lower by a further 1048576 bytes to 30063722496 to be aligned with HeapRegion::GrainBytes
[0.014s][info][cds] Trying to map heap data: region[3] at 0x00000007ffe00000, size =   536576 bytes
[0.014s][info][cds] Trying to map heap data: region[5] at 0x00000007ffd00000, size =   483328 bytes
[0.014s][info][cds] optimized module handling: enabled
[0.014s][info][cds] full module graph: enabled
[0.029s][info][cds] use_full_module_graph = true; java.base = 0x00000008004516a0
[0.029s][info][cds] patching heap embedded pointers
[0.029s][info][cds] Mapped static  region #2 at base 0x00007f4aa4d16000 top 0x00007f4aa4d4e000 (Bitmap)
[0.030s][info][cds] Unmapping region #2 at base 0x00007f4aa4d16000 (Bitmap)
```

Those are logs from second VM where I want to build AppCDS dump and then share it:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Rocky Linux"
VERSION="8.7 (Green Obsidian)"
ID="rocky"
ID_LIKE="rhel centos fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.7"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Rocky Linux 8.7 (Green Obsidian)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
LOGO="fedora-logo-icon"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:rocky:rocky:8:GA"
HOME_URL="https://rockylinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.rockylinux.org/"
ROCKY_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Rocky-Linux-8"
ROCKY_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Rocky Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.7"
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.5.0.8-2.el8_6) (build 17.0.5+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.5.0.8-2.el8_6) (build 17.0.5+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          9.5Gi       1.4Gi       1.8Gi       210Mi       6.3Gi       7.5Gi
Swap:         4.9Gi        46Mi       4.9Gi
```

Appropriate CDS related logs when running application on the first VM with dump made on second VM:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xlog:cds=debug -Xlog:class+load:file=/acds/cds.log -XX:SharedArchiveFile=/acds/app-cds.jsa
[0.006s][info][cds] trying to map /opt/acds/acds.jsa
[0.006s][info][cds] Opened archive /opt/acds/acds.jsa.
[0.006s][info][cds] Archive was created with UseCompressedOops = 1, UseCompressedClassPointers = 1
[0.006s][info][cds] Core region alignment: 4096
[0.006s][info][cds] Reserved archive_space_rs [0x0000000800000000 - 0x0000000803400000] (54525952) bytes
[0.006s][info][cds] Reserved class_space_rs   [0x0000000803400000 - 0x0000000843400000] (1073741824) bytes
[0.006s][info][cds] Mapped static  region #0 at base 0x0000000800000000 top 0x00000008013cd000 (ReadWrite)
[0.006s][info][cds] Mapped static  region #1 at base 0x00000008013cd000 top 0x00000008031aa000 (ReadOnly)
[0.006s][info][cds] UseSharedSpaces: Required classpath entry does not exist: /builds/build/libs/app.jar
[0.006s][info][cds] Unmapping region #0 at base 0x0000000800000000 (ReadWrite)
[0.006s][info][cds] Unmapping region #1 at base 0x00000008013cd000 (ReadOnly)
[0.006s][debug][cds] Released shared space (archive + class) 0x0000000800000000
[0.006s][info ][cds] UseSharedSpaces: Unable to map shared spaces
```

The main is question:

- Does the way how you create CDS dump, the VM configuration matter to make it work? Is there requirements/limitations?
- What `[0.006s][info][cds] UseSharedSpaces: Required classpath entry does not exist: /builds/build/libs/app.jar` could mean?
- What is the best way to create AppCDS in advance in CI and then make it available for use? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I rewrote gradle task with plain bash AppCDS finally worked well. Looks like there is something around how gradle handles sub-processes. Hope that this solution will be useful for someone. Would be great to hear stories how ppl generate AppCDS.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set +e;

var_jar=${1:-$(pwd)/build/libs/app.jar};
var_conf=${2:-$(pwd)/conf/development/conf.json};

function generateAppCdsClasses() {
  echo "Start generating AppCDS class list...";
  declare local var_pid;
  var_acds_list=${1:-$(pwd)/acds.list};
  java \
    -Xlog:cds=debug \
    -XX:DumpLoadedClassList="${var_acds_list}" \
    -jar ${var_jar} \
    -conf "${var_conf}" \
    -options "${var_conf}" 2>&1 &
  var_pid=$!;
  echo "AppCDS classes list PID: ${var_pid}";

  for _ in {1..30}; do
    var_response=$(curl --silent \
      -H "X-Forwarded-For: 38.102.251.12" \
      -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.asd2 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/9${RANDOM}22${RANDOM}22.2.3" \
      "http://localhost:8080/api/healthcheck");
    var_status=$(echo "${var_response}" | jq --exit-status '.status');
    if [[ ${var_status} = "0" ]]; then
      echo "AppCDS class list was successfully generated: ";
      echo "  response: $var_response}";
      echo "  number of classes: $(wc -l < "${var_acds_list}")";
      echo "Start generating AppCDS class list...done";
      kill -9 "${var_pid}";
      return;
    fi
    sleep 1;
  done
  kill -9 "${var_pid}";
  echo "Start generating AppCDS class list...failed";
}

function generateAppCdsDump() {
  echo "Start generating AppCDS dump...";
  declare var_pid;
  var_acds_list=${1:-$(pwd)/acds.list};
  var_acds_dump=${2:-$(pwd)/acds.jsa};
  java \
    -Xlog:cds=debug \
    -Xshare:dump \
    -XX:SharedArchiveFile="${var_acds_dump}" \
    -XX:SharedClassListFile="${var_acds_list}" \
    -jar ${var_jar} \
    -conf "${var_conf}" \
    -options "${var_conf}" 2>&1 &
  sleep 10;
  du -sh "${var_acds_dump}";
  echo "Start generating AppCDS dump...done";
}

function acds() {
  var_acds_list="$(pwd)/acds.list";
  var_acds_dump="$(pwd)/acds.jsa";
  var_dest="$(pwd)/build/acds/";
  rm -rf "${var_acds_list}" "${var_acds_dump}";
  generateAppCdsClasses "${var_acds_list}";
  generateAppCdsDump "${var_acds_list}" "${var_acds_dump}";
  mkdir -p "${var_dest}";
  mv "${var_acds_dump}" "${var_dest}";
}
```